# Is it possible to configure exact date format of discussions in GitLab merge requests?

Tags: gitlab

Now, in GitLab, if you got old discussion, you can see only the short variant of date, like "5 months ago"

[image]

It is not convenient, if you got many merge requests, all of them 5 months ago, and you what to compare what of discussion in merge requests was earlier

It it possible to configure view of date format in all of GitLab or just in discussions?

Comment: Note, if you put the mouse cursor over the "5 months ago" text it will show the exact date and time. Of course that's a bit less convenient, but until you have an answer here to change the formatting you can at least check the time manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no possibility to change this UI behavior.

In the merge request threads are arranged in the order in which they were created.

Also it is possible to move mouse cursor over the date and get more exact date value in format: 
`Nov 27, 2023 3:52pm GMT+0200`